# Testing PayPal payouts

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-adaptive-payments, payout

I've seen the requirements for the `Paypal Payout`. It says that accounts should be business type and that the platform account should request a payout access to PayPal. I'm from the Philippines, but my client is in Australia so they can make the business account and request payout access. My question is, once we got access to payouts, can we test the payout on sandbox mode? or the payout only works with real paypal credits/money?

Answer (score 0):

Payouts always works for sandbox Business accounts of countries that support payouts. Create such accounts in [the developer dashboard](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts), logging in with any live PayPal account.